# save raw file into internal storage

Tags: android, storage, internal

I have a text file in raw folder and now i want to save it somewhere in the internal storage in android platform so that it is non-accessible.

Please if someone can help me out. Thanx in advance.

Comment: could you please add more information in the title? two lines are not enough...

Answer (score -2):

Something like this should work

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("path_to_your_file");
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("your_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// read from InputStream and write ot OutputStream
```

More info about [InternalStorage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)